# Walking between points

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have written a function that fills in the values between points and creates one continuous path (essentially walks between the points) and I'd like some feedback on it's implementation.

If two points are provided that are not "in line" with one another then an error is thrown, as I do not want to support diagonal movement.

Here is an example of the code's input and output:

**The route to walk**

```
|_Point_|_X_|_Y_|
| A     | 0 | 0 |
| B     | 2 | 0 |
| C     | 2 | 2 |
| D     | 2 | 4 |
| E     | 4 | 4 |
```

**Diagram of the route in 2D space**

```
  0_1_2_3_4_X
0|A   B
1|
2|    C
3|
4|    D   E
Y|
```

**Calling the walk function**

```js
const output = walk(
  { x: 0, y: 0 }, // A
  { x: 2, y: 0 }, // B
  { x: 2, y: 2 }, // C
  { x: 2, y: 4 }, // D
  { x: 4, y: 4 }  // E
);
```

**The output from the walk function**

```js
[
  { x: 0, y: 0 }, // A
  { x: 1, y: 0 }, // A -> B
  { x: 2, y: 0 }, // B
  { x: 2, y: 1 }, // B -> C
  { x: 2, y: 2 }, // C
  { x: 2, y: 3 }, // C -> D
  { x: 2, y: 4 }, // D
  { x: 3, y: 4 }, // D -> E
  { x: 4, y: 4 }  // E
]
```

And the function itself:

```js
function walk(...points) {
  const result = [];
  let lastPoint = null;

  points.forEach((point, index) => {
    if (lastPoint === null) {
      result.push(point);
    } else {
      const direction = {
        x: Math.sign(point.x - lastPoint.x),
        y: Math.sign(point.y - lastPoint.y)
      };

      if (direction.x !== 0 && direction.y !== 0) {
        throw new Error(`points are misaligned at ${index}`);
      } else if (direction.x % 1 !== 0 || direction.y % 1 !== 0) {
        throw new Error(`points must be whole values at ${index}`);
      } else if (direction.x === 0 && direction.y === 0) {
        return;
      }

      const axis = direction.x !== 0 ? 'x' : 'y',
            otherAxis = axis === 'x' ? 'y' : 'x';

      const start = lastPoint[axis] + direction[axis],
            comparator = direction[axis] > 0 ? (a, b) => a <= b : (a, b) => a >= b,
            delta = direction[axis];

      for (let value = start; comparator(value, point[axis]); value += delta) {
        result.push({
          [axis]: value,
          [otherAxis]: point[otherAxis]
        });
      }
    }

    lastPoint = point;
  });

  return result;
}
```

**Things I think could be improved**

1. I don't like how the `comparator` variable works — it seems a bit of a hack and there's most likely a more mathematical way of working it out.
2. Are there more "ES6-y" ways of doing what I've done? For example using `reduce` or similar functions.

Answer (score 2):

This condition

```
else if (direction.x % 1 !== 0 || direction.y % 1 !== 0)
```

Doesn't check for integer and is (almost) always false, since `direction.x` is the result of [`Math.sign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign), which returns an integer (`1`, `0`, or `-1`) or `NaN`, which is the only time the condition can be true.

Use `point.x` instead. I would also use [`Number.isInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) to check for integers. This check should also be at the start of your loop, since the first point of the input is currently not getting checked.

---

I'm not sure what this code is supposed to accomplish.

```
else if (direction.x === 0 && direction.y === 0) {
  return;
}
```

What is the desires behavior when you get two identical point after each other? Is it illegal? Throw an error. Should it keep both points? Don't do anything. Should duplicates be deleted? Replace `return` with `continue` so it won't get added to the result.

Comment: I am returning when there is no direction as it means that there is a duplicate input point which is ignored (only the first one is used). Returning actually only skips the current iteration, as I'm using [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). This is also why I'm using `return` instead of `continue`.

Comment: You are right, I forgot forEach was using a callback function